# Ruby: Removing arrays from a 2d array that match a certain string

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have a 2d array that looks like

```
array = [["apples", 10], ["bananas", 20], ["plums", 30], ["oranges", 10]]
```

and another array that looks like

```
badstuff_array = ["bananas","plums"]
```

and I want to remove the arrays from `array` that contain anything from `badstuff_array`.
So the output would look like

```
goodstuff_array = [["apples", 10],["oranges", 10]]
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: what have you tried so far? look into the core lib functions of enumerables like `include?`, `select`, `reject`

Comment: Look at [`delete_if`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-delete_if).

Comment: I tried something like `array.delete_if{|fruit, count| fruit & badstuff_array}` but it's giving me type errors on the &

Comment: Yeah the `fruit & badstuff_array` expression doesn't make any sense. Do you know what the `&` operator is for? You wanted, really, `badstuff_array.include? fruit`.

Comment: Well the fruits are strings and the contents of `badstuff_array`are strings and I thought that `deleteif there's an intersection between the two` made sense. I need to get used to using more than one of the core lib functions together.

Comment: `fruit` itself is not a set. It's just a string representing the fruit. You could perhaps have said `.delete_if {|fruit,_| ([fruit] & badstuff_array) != []}` to make a single-element set out of `fruit`. Otherwise, you're trying to intersect a string with a set, which won't work. Note also that set intersection will be "true" even if the result is the empty set. So you have to explicitly check for "not the empty set" in that approach.

Comment: huh. thanks for the tips and the comments @lurker. They're much appreciated. I still have a lot to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done quite easily with a combination of [`Array#delete_if`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-delete_if) and [`Array#include?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-include-3F):

```
array.delete_if{|x| badstuff_array.include? x[0]}
#=> [["apples", 10], ["oranges", 10]]
```

Comment: I find the `_` variable a good use case for this: `arr.delete_if{|_,x| badstuff.include? x }`

Comment: @DMKE you mean `|x,_|`